# Deinit is not called when assign NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

This is how I declare property in my subclass of `UIViewController`:

```
private weak var timer: NSTimer?
```

This is what I do in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And this is my `deinit`:

```
deinit {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

Deinit is not called because of `NSTimer`. Do not make funny telling that inside `NSTimer` there is a strong reference to my controller:) How can I workaround this?

Comment: You could invalidate the timer in [`viewWillDisappear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @i_am_jorf gave you a good direction. If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate) of invalidate method you will find a full explanation why it is acting like that

> This method is the only way to remove a timer from an NSRunLoop object. The NSRunLoop object removes its strong reference to the timer, either just before the invalidate method returns or at some later point.
>
> If it was configured with target and user info objects, the receiver removes its strong references to those objects as well.

So yes, retain cycle created if invalidate not called in an appropriate moment